# Are enum types declared in a class implicitly static?

Tags: java, enums

```
class Coffee{   
   enum CoffeeSize{BIG,HUGE,OVERWHELMING}   
   CoffeeSize size;   
  }   

class CoffeeTest{   
   public static void main(String[] args)   
  {   
       Coffee drink=new Coffee();   
       drink.size=Coffee.CoffeeSize.BIG;   
   }   
}
```

`Coffee.CoffeeSize.BIG`: i can get `CoffeeSize` just using the class name `Coffee`. Am I correct when I think the enum type is implicitly static?

Comment: When you think about what enums represent and how they are supposed to be used, you have to admit they can only be static.

Comment: Rephrased this to make it a question

Comment: It appears we missed the same question with the same answer on the self check for chapter 1 :(

After review, this should have been obvious considering they can't be instantiated..

Comment: **Update:** Local enums, defined within a method, will be a feature in Java 16, previewing in Java 15. See: [*JEP 384: Records (Second Preview)*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/384). Discussed in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62807591/642706) on another page.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it is. The language specification even says so. From the [JLS section 8.9 (enums)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.9):

> Nested enum types are implicitly static. It is permissable to explicitly declare a nested enum type to be static.

Comment: +1 But only if you do get the reference eventually. :)