# why enums only on a top level class or interface?

Tags: java, enums

I am studying Java and wrote a very simple program. In it I can put enums in the top most level, but not inside a method. The way I see it, enums are almost like constants, so why not use them inside methods?

In my program, enum1 is allowed, but enum2 is not. Why?

```
enum enum1 {A, B, C};

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    enum enum2 {A, B, C};  // only on a top level class or interface
}
```

Comment: See this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026626/why-java-doesnt-allow-to-define-enum-within-a-method

Comment: So, you are just pointing to another question which says that they don't know what is the reason....

Comment: @user2864740 But WHY? It is the same thing as saying that you can have any color, except BLUE.

Comment: @user2864740 Not entirely true; classes *can* be defined inside methods. (Try it!).

Comment: @Jesper Well, hmmpf. I was wrong, what a curious construct.

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, it's a little-known feature, and almost nobody uses it, but it's possible.

Comment: **Update:** Local enums, defined within a method, will be a feature in Java 16, previewing in Java 15. See: [*JEP 384: Records (Second Preview)*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/384). Discussed in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62807591/642706) on another page.

Answer (score 8):

Because enums are a special type of class definition.

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) doc describes some information about special things the compiler does including adding static methods (valueOf). While you could declare an anonymous class withing the context of a method, it could not have static methods.

Answer (score 3):

It may have to do with the fact that Enums are compiled similarly to classes. For the same reason you cannot declare a class definition inside a method, you cannot declare in enum either.

Comment: But you can declare classes inside a method. Granted, they are anonymous classes, but they are still declared inside a method.

Comment: These are non-anonymous. @Brett Okken linked the documentation is his answer.

Comment: Never said they weren't - just making a point of clarification.

Comment: @Stendika It's a little-known feature of Java, but you *can* actually define non-anonymous classes inside methods. Try it yourself...

Answer (score 1):

Enums in Java are actually creating a class, which causes them to have limitations like this.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 0):

Enumerations are way more than constant, you can create constructor for them. They are like Classes, you can't define a class in a method, it's the same for enumeration.
If you want constant, you should better consider using final static var