# Why in Java enums are not allowed in method?

Tags: java, enums

Java does not allow enum to be declared in a method that is a basic java syntax.

**But**

Could any body explain **why** is that, what could have gone wrong if it would have been allowed by Java, I am sure there must be some cause behind this restriction, any idea?

```
class Example {

    void aMethod() {

        //This is not allowed
        enum Status {
            NEW,
            PROCESSING,
            COMPLETED;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: These types of questions are fairly pointless, since noone can know the answer except for the language spec designers. I imagine though that the use of enums inside a method was deemed pointless, I can't think of a situation where it sould make sense to use it.

Comment: Can you describe your use case when you would actually want this feature?

Comment: **Update:** Local enums, defined within a method, will be a feature in Java 16, previewing in Java 15. See: [*JEP 384: Records (Second Preview)*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/384). Discussed in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62807591/642706) on another page.

Answer (score 1):

`enum` types are typically used to share constant values between classes so declaring them in the scope of a method wouldnt make any sense